# It said parcelRequire is not defined when i'm using socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, parceljs

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCr7D.png)

I use import like this

```js
import { io } from "./lib/socket.io.esm.min.js";
```

And I copied socket.io/client/socket.io.esm.min.js to ./lib/socket.io.esm.min.js

Comment: Why do you think `parcelRequire()` has anything to do with socket.io?  This error seems to be related to different code.  Also, please paste the text of the error directly into the question, not as an image.

Comment: I use webpack and it works